# How to automatically trace build output errors back to CMake (or similar) build descriptor

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

If there is an error in CMakeLists.txt that causes a build time error, is there a way to automatically trace the build time error back to the offending lines in CMakeLists.txt?  (Kinda like how a debugger allows you to step through source code rather than machine code.)  If not, is there a tool similar to CMake that has this feature, or a feature that can be used in a similar way?

An example is where the build directory was used by mistake as part of the include path instead of the source directory.  The compile error was that `filex.h` was not found.  The build log shows the list compiler flags, some of which are the include search locations, but these are given as absolute paths on the build machine.  If these were "reversed" back to the expressions in the CMakeLists.txt file that generated them, errors like this would be easier to troubleshoot.